# unable to determine the template type even it is passed in

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Data {
   struct Embed
   { 
      T t;
   };
};

struct Functor {
  template <typename T>
  void foo( typename Data<T>::Embed & e) {}
};
template <typename T, typename F>
struct Caller
{
  F f;
  template <typename T>
  void invoke() {
    typename Data<T>::Embed e;
    f.foo<T>(e); //compiler error pointed this line
   }
 };
```

Then I specialized the template as:

```
 Caller<int, Functor> c;
 c.invoke();
```

compiler error is : `error: expected primary-expression before '>'` in `f.foo<T>(e);` line. It seems compiler suddenly doesn't know what T is even it is specified in the template declaration on the function.

Take out the explicit specified `T` in `foo.invoke(e)` line will result `could not deduce template parameter 'T'`

How do I fix this? (I still want to keep the functionality that Caller can have generic functor and functor's function can be templated).

Comment: It could be that you are reusing the same template name for `invoke()` as you have for `Caller`.  I don't think that is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
template <typename T>
void invoke() {
   typename Data<T>::Embed e;
   f.foo<T>(e); //compiler error pointed this line
}
```

inside `Caller` even though `T` is one of the parameters of `Caller`. Remove the line

```
template <typename T>
```

and use just:

```
void invoke() {
   typename Data<T>::Embed e;
   // f.foo<T>(e);   //compiler error pointed this line
   f.template foo<T>(e); // Need the template keyword here.
}
```

However, as @Nawaz pointed out in a comment, that changes the semantics of `invoke`. If `T` in `invoke` was meant to be different than the `T` used to instantiate `Caller`, then it will be better to use a different name, say `U`.

Comment: I think it changes the semantic. `T` in `invoke` might be different from `T` of the class template. `f.foo<T>(e)` needs to be written as `f.template foo<T>()`.

Comment: @Nawaz, true. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Nawaz I don't think OP wants `invoke` to be a template - the semantics desired were `c.invoke();`

Comment: @Barry: Maybe, either way, the `template` keyword is **required**.

Comment: @Nawaz, I agree that the `template` keyword is required. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @Barry is correct that the calling semantics should be no template. @R Sahu answer is not completely right since foo's parameter is templated so you can not remove the template function declaration.

Comment: @user2426361, yes, you can. See http://ideone.com/xtlXAV.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks, that is what I want and more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `f` is of type `F` which is template parameter, `f.foo` is a dependent name and which happens to be a function *template*. So you've to use `template` in a very weird way:

```
f.template foo<T>(e);
```

For further explantion, see these:

- [short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660958/strange-compilation-behaviour-when-calling-a-template-method-from-another-templa)
- [long explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Also, I'd advise you to use `U` as template parameter for the function template `invoke` **if** at all it needs to be a template, else you can make it a normal function (i.e if the `T` of invoke is ought to be same as `T` of the enclosing class template).

Hope that helps.